# Proof by induction $\sum_{i=1}^{d} i*2^{d-i}\leq 2^{d+1}-d-2 \ \forall d \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Proof by induction $$\sum_{i=1}^{d} i*2^{d-i}\leq 2^{d+1}-d-2 \ \forall d \in \mathbb{N}$$

I got to

$$[2\sum_{i=1}^{d} i*2^{d-i}] + (d+1) \leq 2[2^{d+1}-d-2] -1 $$

and don't know how to proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: You misused the induction hypothesis

Comment: i think your sum is equal to $$2^{d+1}-2-d$$

Answer (score 2):

When $d=1$, LHS = $1$ and RHS = $1$ so a basis for induction is established.

Let $P(d)$ be the proposition that $\sum_{i=1}^{d} i \cdot2^{d-i}\leq 2^{d+1}-d-2$

Induction hypothesis: suppose $P(k)$ is true (for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$), so $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} i \cdot2^{k-i}\leq 2^{k+1}-k-2$$

Consider $d=k+1$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i \cdot2^{k+1-i}=(k+1)+2\sum_{i=1}^{k} i \cdot2^{k-i}\leq k+1+2(2^{k+1}-k-2)=2^{(k+1)+1}-(k+1)-2$$ Hence $P(k+1)$ is true, so by Mathematical Induction, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

It is true for $d=1$ because $1\cdot 1=2^2-1-2$

Suppose it is true for $d$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{d} i\cdot 2^{d-i}\leq 2^{d+1}-d-2;\;\quad I.H.$$
Let's prove it for $d+1$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{d+1} i\cdot 2^{d}\leq 2^{d+2}-d-3$$
Indeed 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{d+1} i\cdot 2^{d}\leq 2^d\,\sum_{i=1}^{d} i+d+1=2\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^{d} i\cdot 2^{d-1}}+d+1\leq$$
$$2\left(2^{d+1}-d-2\right)+d+1\leq 2^{d+2}-2d-4+d+1=2^{d+2}-d-3$$
proved!

Hope this helps